# Problem with opening .las files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, las, laz

For the last few days I tried to open .las Files from my work into QGIS. I have heard that the newest version of QGIS is able to open .las .laz files without any problem. The problem is that the whenever I try to drag down the .las files into QGIS, the Data wont show any XYZ or RGB attributes.

A colleague of tried to open the files in Geograf and it works just fine.
I am not sure what the problem is.

Does anyone have similar problem with this?

Comment: which QGIS-Version do you use?

Comment: When you open a *las* file with QGIS it creates a folder ```ept_*filename*``` in the las file folder's. If you open the ```ept.json``` who is in this folder and look in the ```"schema"``` part the fields X,Y,Z and R,G,B appear and are their ```min``` and ```max``` values consistent?

Comment: I am now using Qgis 3.22.3- Bialowieza

I could see the ept_*filename* but it seems that couldnt find any ept.json

Comment: @PaskalvinPutraBaruna It's strange that you don't have any ```ept.json``` file. Do you only see the las bbox and no points ? If so, look this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423581/french-point-cloud-data-wont-render-properly-in-qgis-3-22-3

Comment: I checked up the las file version, v1.1 was supported well with QGIS3.22, But v1.2 was loaded unnormally - no data after decoding.Is QGIS not fit for different versions of las?